# Combobox freezes after readding to parent

Tags: java, combobox, javafx-8

this time I am prepared with an example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class testMain extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testMain.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        VBox root = new VBox(5);

        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10, 5, 10, 5));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox<>();
        cb.getItems().addAll("content 1" , "content 2",  "content 3");

        Label label = new Label("shows content");

        cb.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            ComboBox<String> newCb = cb;
            root.getChildren().clear();
            Label newLabel = new Label(newValue);
            root.getChildren().addAll(newLabel, cb);
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(label, cb);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

In my programm I add a variable number of Vboxes to the root, depending on the selection from the dropbox. Thatswhy I need to clear the children-list and rebuild it from scratch (is the easiest way^^).

The problem is, that the combo-box freezes after the first selection, is there a way to avoid this or to make it working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug.

That said, I would strongly encourage you not to implement it this way. You could, for example, use a `BorderPane` with the combo box in the bottom and the `VBox` in the center. Then just rebuild the `VBox`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane ;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class TestMain extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {


        VBox vbox = new VBox(5);

        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 5, 10, 5));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(vbox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox<>();
        root.setBottom(cb);

        cb.getItems().addAll("content 1" , "content 2",  "content 3");

        Label label = new Label("shows content");

        cb.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            vbox.getChildren().clear();
            Label newLabel = new Label(newValue);
            vbox.getChildren().addAll(newLabel);
        });

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Or, with the design you have, just don't remove the combo box:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Arrays ;


public class testMain extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        VBox root = new VBox(5);

        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10, 5, 10, 5));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox<>();
        cb.getItems().addAll("content 1" , "content 2",  "content 3");

        Label label = new Label("shows content");

        cb.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            root.getChildren().removeIf(node -> node != cb);
            Label newLabel = new Label(newValue);
            root.getChildren().addAll(0, Arrays.asList(newLabel));
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(label, cb);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: removeIf()...  I will give it a try!

Comment: Well done it worked! Due to the insignificance i will not report this glitch.